# Not enough information to check signature validity of the signature for the browser bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, verification

I have downloaded the most recent package of the Tor Browser Bundle and I am attempting to verify the signature using gpg. I have imported the key and downloaded the signature file, but when I attempt to verify the signature of the file I get the message "Not enough information to check signature validity." Why did I receive this message?

I am right clicking on the signature file and using the verify command under More GpgEX options. I am naming the torbrowser-install-3.5_en-US.exe file as the signed data.

Comment: We need a little bit more information.  Are you using gpg?  If so, what's the exact command you are invoking?

Comment: What is the exact command to do this in gpg4win? I really have not figured out how to use gpg and want to verify my tor bundle tbb 3.5. is there a graphical way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the keys for verifying the signature.

Check [this page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) on how to do the verification process.